# 'http_proxy' had unsupported trailing in .curlrc config file

Tags: bash, curl, configuration

url="http://saimei.acc.umu.se/debian-cd/8.5.0/i386/iso-cd/debian-8.5.0-i386-netinst.iso"
wget -c $url    -O /tmp/debian.iso

```
url="http://saimei.acc.umu.se/debian-cd/8.5.0/i386/iso-cd/debian-8.5.0-i386-netinst.iso"
curl -x "vps_ip:80" $url -o  /tmp/netinst.iso
```

No error info output,now i want to write the http_proxy in curl configuration file.

```
vim /root/.curlrc
http_proxy="http://vps_ip:80"
```

Let's to start curl.

```
curl  $url -o  /tmp/netinst.iso

Warning: /root/.curlrc:1: warning: 'http_proxy' had unsupported trailing 
Warning: garbage
```

What is matter with /root/.curlrc ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following instead:

```
proxy=http://vps_ip:80
```